# Struggling a bit with Combinatorics Order in which to do this question?

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

n P 4 = 84 n C 2 
Now I'm not even sure if the 84 is multiplying by the N choose 2? I don't understand. 
Ive done all the practice questions my teacher gave me and this came up on the homework and Ive never encountered a question like this. 
Thanks in advance. 
Is there a specific order to do questions like this, how would you go about doing this question?

Comment: what does your first statement actually mean?

Comment: Probably it is solve the equation ${}_n\text{P}_4=(84)({}_n\text{C}_2)$.  So we want $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)=42n(n-1)$.  The rest should not be hard.  Note that we can probably assume $n\ge 4$, so can cancel stuff.

Comment: @user190080 The question seems to be about the order of operations - the questioner does not understand if they should multiply the $n$ by 84 and then evaluate the function or evaluate the function first, then multiply by 84.

Comment: @tomi: I have parentheses on the right in order to make my interpretation clear.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Your comment is perfectly clear (and I have upvoted it) - I was commenting on the comment before yours.

Comment: @tomi ah I see, the thing is that I've never seen an expression like nPr before, is this standard notation?

Comment: @user190080 The $P$ is for "Permutations" - ${}_nP_r$ is the number of permutations that can be made of $r$ objects chosen from a set of $n$ objects. The $C$ is for "Combinations" - ${}_nC_r$ is the number of combinations that can be made of $r$ objects chosen from a set of $n$ objects. In a combination the order does not matter, but in a permutation the order does matter.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Sorry, Ive just never seen a question like this before. Its funny how the real assignment shows things I've never done yet. I didnt know you had to divide 84 by the 2.

Comment: Still kind of struggling. If you guys had to do the whole equation, how would you do it? and in what order? I know you have to cancel stuff out, but its the whole dividing by each side, subract from one side and add it to the other that throws me off. When do I need to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you have to solve the equation $${}_nP_4=84\times {}_nC_2$$

It only makes sense as a question if you are multiplying by $84$ that way: ${}_nP_4={}_{84n}C_2$ is impossible.

Use the definitions $${}_nP_r=\frac {n!}{(n-r)!}$$ and $${}_nC_r=\frac {n!}{n!(n-r)!}$$

Comment: Thanks Ill get to work on it. :)